# CSS for Wordpress Contact Form 7 checkbox without divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress, customization, contact-form

I have searched the forum and google and this particular issue seems easy to solve but I cannot find the answer. I want to stylize the checkbox for Contact Form 7 without using divs. But the style I want to use are the ones that use divs. For example I want to use the styling for SQUARE ONE from this example: http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

Since the example I provided above uses divs (which I don't mind) Contact Form 7 doesn't seem to work since it requires more than one div to compass the form field. Here's the code I'm trying to format:

```
<p>What are you interested in? Select all that apply. (required)<br />
[checkbox* service-interested "Item 1" "Item 2" "Item 3" "Item 4" "Item 5" "Other"] </p>
```

This is the original post to help stylize http://contactform7.com/styling-contact-form/

Comment: Why not add a class to the checkbox and style that?

Comment: You might not realize that for most browsers, there's no way to restyle checkboxes and radio buttons via pure css. So whenever you find a solution that shows fancy graphics instead of the standard checkbox/radio button, it's always built as a visual replacement for these elements. This always involves extra markup (mostly divs) and in most cases also Javascript to mimic the correct behaviour, including being able to access the element in keyboard navigation.

Comment: Ahh so basically there is no way. :(
@Howli I particularly wanted the effect in the example shown and the only way to do it is via divs. Since I can't break up the contact form (which acts different from a simple html form) I'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code pen fork of yours.

http://codepen.io/Yeswanth-JG/pen/bNWyVd

```
<span class="slideone">
"..."
</span>
```

CSS

```
.slideone {
        display: block;
     }
```

You should set display property to 'block' for the tags other than the tags which are block ones by default...

So, for the slide one... I had given span & given display as block, 'It Works!'..

NOTE: You can also give display as inline-block, but with little care...ll